# How can I define an async function in an object literal

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Whenever I try to define an async function inside an object this way it throws a Syntax error.

```
let obj = {
  fn: async function fn() {
    return 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: Async functions are part of ES2017, which is to be released soon, not ES7 (which as released last year).

Comment: If it throws a syntax error then the environment you want to run the code in doesn't support async functions.

Comment: *What* syntax error does it throw?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you posted is syntactically correct. If you are getting a syntax error then the environment you are trying to run the code in doesn't support async functions (which is not necessarily surprising giving that this feature hasn't been officially released yet).

Solutions:

- Don't use async functions (use promises directly instead)
- Transform your code before executing it with something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

---

Information about which environment supports async functions can be found at https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-async_functions .